# remove typeahead.js event from input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I have a checkbox that triggers whether a typeahead feature is enabled on an input box or not. This is what I have on the 'change' event:

```
$("#checkbox").change(function() {
  if ($("#checkbox").prop('checked')) {
    $("#input").typeahead({
              local: ['a', 'b']
            });
  } else {
      //remove typeahead from the input box
  }
 });
```

How can I remove the typeahead feature in an else statement above?

Comment: does it use the jquery ui framework? if yes: `$('#input').typeahead('destroy');`

Comment: try $('#input').unbind();

Comment: it's Twitter's typeahead.js -- http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ -- and yes, your solution works.

Comment: @VinodLouis: that would unbind ALL events... really bad idea

Comment: hmm you're correct i think $('#input').removeClass('dropdown-menu'); can also work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#jquerytypeaheaddestroy) you can achieve this using:

```
$('#input').typeahead('destroy');
```

Comment: lame...I missed that. Thanks.